MS Project: correct redistribution of resources in a fixed work activity when change the duration
I'm using Microsoft Project 365 and I've the following problem:
from a fixed work activity, if I add one or more resources in the task, the duration decreases correctly. Instead, if I decreases the duration, of course i have a problem of overallocation. Now, when I choose the option "assign other resources", the program doesn't solve the problem.
An example: I've a task in fixed work of 480h (60 days of 1 person).

I try to change the duration in 30 days, and of course i've a problem of overallocation:

then, I choose the option "assign other resources", but the result is the following:

the program has assegned 320h and 160h, with a duration of 20 days, when the solution is banal that is a duration of 30 days with 240h of work for each person.
How is possible to solve it? I've tried also with the leveling of resources, but without success.
thank
